# Set Of String??!!

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

You are familiar with this block:

```
Var
  mySet: Set Of Char;
  C: Char;
begin
  mySet := ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  If C In mySet Then ShowMessage('Exists');
end;
```

Is there any way to declare `Set Of STRING`? or is there similar code that i can use instead? The important part of this block is `If C In mySet Then ShowMessage('Exists');` I wanna use something like this about a set of string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The RTL `System.StrUtils` unit provides a very interesting method for this:

```
function MatchText(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean; overload;
```

Use it like this:

```
  if MatchText(sLanguages, ['fr-FR', 'en-GB', 'de-DE', 'it-IT', 'fr-CH', 'es-ES']) then
    Writeln('found')
```

Comment: This creates an array of [0..5] of String at compile time and passes it to the function.  Pros: It's 1 line.  That's nice in very limited situations.  E.G. Is this string allowed in that Field?  Cons: If you use that 1-liner twice you've induced a bug.  The maintainer of your code may change that set in one instance and miss the other.  Also,the RTL is performing an inefficient linear search of that array using string compare.  Pos(sLanguages,'fr-FR,en-GB,de-DE,it-IT,fr-CH,es-ES')>0 would be faster -- and still not a good idea.

Comment: @GuyGordon 1. the MatchText function is defined as follows: function MatchText(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean; -> the array argument can refer to a const reference, like "const cStrings: array of string = ['fr-FR', 'en-GB', 'de-DE', 'it-IT', 'fr-CH', 'es-ES']". -> the array is now referenced in only one place, ie what you wanted. 2. Your proposal of using the "Pos" gives wrong result, because it wrongly accepts strings like "fr" or "GB".

Comment: Oops.  You're right, thanks.  You have to put delimiters around the substrings, and around the search string.  And it's case sensitive.  Like I said, not a good idea.

Answer (score 13):

Sets are implemented using bit arrays.  So no, you cannot have a 'set of string'.  Use a TStringList instead, ie:

```
var 
  mySet: TStringList;
  S: String;
begin 
  S := ...;
  mySet := TStringList.Create;
  try
    mySet.Add('a');
    mySet.Add('b');
    mySet.Add('c'); 
    if mySet.IndexOf(S) <> -1 Then ShowMessage('Exists');
  finally
    mySet.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you have a lot of strings, it could be better to use sorted list and ignore duplicates:

mySet.Sorted := True;
mySet.Duplicates := dupIgnores;

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of this.

```
type 
  TAnyEnum = (aeVal1, aeVal2, aeVal3);
  TEnuns = set of TAnyEnum;
  TAnyMessages: array [TAnyEnum] of String;

const 
  MyMessages: TAnyMessages = ('Exists', 'Something else', 'WTF!?');

var
  MySet : TEnums;
begin
  MySet = [aeVal1, aeVal2];
  If aeVal1 in MySet then ShowMessage(MyMessages[aeVal1]);
end;
```

Comment: to answer correctly the question, the entry point should be a string, not an enumerated type. -> the question is not respected

Comment: @DidierCabalé  But an Delphi set **MUST** be based on a **ORDINAL** type. Strings are NOT ordinal types. 
The nearer you can get of a set of strings is that.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo, it depends on where you focus on: if it is on using *Set of*, I agree that this is the nearest. But this does not answer the fundamental question that is *how to know if a specific string is in a set of string*, and in that case, you cannot use the Pascal construct "set of"

Answer (score 3):

It is shame, but Delphi still don't have even very basic data structures, like sets.
Suggestion of "Fabricio Araujo" is very limited in usage - you have to know all possible strings, so it is useless when you read them from somewhere. It is also impossible to have more then 256 items in such "alsmost set of strings". Remy Lebeau suggested to use TStringList for that purpose, but it is absolutely inefficient when you have big sets. In modern versions of Delphi it is possible to use TDictionary to keep unordered set of anything, including strings:

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
type
  TEmpty = record end;
var
  MySet: TDictionary<String, TEmpty>;
  Dummy: TEmpty;
begin
  MySet := TDictionary<String, TEmpty>.Create;
  try
    MySet.Add('Str1', Dummy);
    MySet.Add('Str2', Dummy);
    MySet.Add('Str3', Dummy);
    if MySet.TryGetValue('Str2', Dummy) then
      ShowMessage('Exists');;
  finally
    MySet.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It is case sensitive. If you need case insensitive implementation, you can make all strings lowercased before put/look then in set (use AnsiLowerCase function for that).

Comment: Most of time I use an Dictionary in .NET is for cases when my solution would suffice.

Comment: "so it is useless when you read them from somewhere". No, is not useless. Instead of using an array constant, use an array **variable** and fill it from source you want.

Answer (score 1):

Fabricio Araujo posted the best answer to the original question.
But if you are asking that question you should also ask yourself
"Do I **only** need to know if Str is in this Set?".

For the question "Is MonthAbbr in the set of allowed abbreviations of month names?"
chances are your next question is "Well then, which month **is** it?".

- You code should answer both questions in one function call.  (e.g. return Month Number else 0)
- Should be **Readable**.  Make your **intent** imediatly clear to the code maintainer.
- Should store the allowed strings in a single **obvious** place in code.
- Should allow easy revision ("Add 'Fall' and 'Autumn' and bring that back to me in 15 min.").
- Be reasonably efficient for the expected size of the set.
- Use the standard library (VCL) if possible.  Else use an external library.
- If your code does this sort of thing often, separate the strings from the implementation, and put the implementation in one place so it can be changed cleanly.

So your code might read
`case GetMonthNumber(Str) of
  0: //Error: Str is not a Month Name or Abbreviation
  1: //etc.`

For the implementation, the simplest general answer is to use a sorted TStringList in Delphi 7 (as the question is tagged).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to declare a new "String" type and use a RECORD HELPER to implement the "IN" operator on it:

```
USES System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils;

TYPE
  TextString    = RECORD
                  PRIVATE
                    STR                 : STRING;
                  PUBLIC
                    CLASS OPERATOR      Implicit(CONST S : STRING) : TextString; INLINE;
                    CLASS OPERATOR      Implicit(CONST S : TextString) : STRING; INLINE;
                  END;
{ TextString }

CLASS OPERATOR TextString.Implicit(CONST S : STRING) : TextString;
  BEGIN
    Result.STR:=S
  END;

CLASS OPERATOR TextString.Implicit(CONST S : TextString) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=S.STR
  END;

TYPE
  TStringHelper = RECORD HELPER FOR TextString
                    CLASS OPERATOR In(CONST T : TextString ; CONST ARR : ARRAY OF STRING) : BOOLEAN;
                    FUNCTION       IsEmpty : BOOLEAN;
                  END;

{ TStringHelper }

CLASS OPERATOR TStringHelper.In(CONST T : TextString ; CONST ARR : ARRAY OF STRING) : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=MatchText(T.STR,ARR)
  END;

FUNCTION TStringHelper.IsEmpty : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=STR.IsEmpty
  END;

VAR
  S     : TextString;
  T     : STRING;

begin
  try
    REPEAT
      WRITE('Enter an animal name: '); READLN(T); S:=T;
      IF S.IsEmpty THEN EXIT;
      IF S IN ['Bird','Lion','Monkey'] THEN WRITELN('You got it!') ELSE WRITELN('Nope - Try Again...')
    UNTIL FALSE
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

It is implicitly compatible with STRING type in assignments and comparisons. It is implicitly case insensitive in the "IN" operator, and by extending the record helper (with Equal/NotEqual/GreaterThan/LessThan/GreaterThanOrEqual/LessThanOrEqual operators to STRING and TextString types) you can make a fully-case-insensitive string type.

Disadvantage: You cannot use this new type in VAR/OUT STRING parameters, and it's a little bit slower than a standard STRING type due to its conversion back and forth and UPPER-casing in comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

function **MatchStr**(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean; overload;

MatchStr determines if any of the strings in the array AValues match the string specified by AText using a **case sensitive** comparison. It returns true if at least one of the strings in the array match, or false if none of the strings match.

For a **case insensitive match**, use the **MatchText** routine.